# Excel formula to calculate payday(15th and EOM)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm looking for an excel formula to calculate if a date is a payday, if the paydays are 15th and EOM.  Of course taking into consideration if 15th or EOM fall on a weekend, logic would mean you are paid the Friday before.  Also considering bank Holidays schedule.

Thus far I've come up with:
`=IF(DAY('Date')=15, 'Y',IF('Date'='EOM(date)', 'N',''))`

I'm calculating the **'EOM(date)'** using
`=WORKDAY(WORKDAY(EOMONTH('Date',0),1),-1)`

Sample set of end data required:

```
     Date      | Paycheck  
  10/15/2013   |    Y
  10/14/2013   |    N
```

Comment: You can actually get EOM with the simpler `=WORKDAY(EOMONTH('Date',0)+1,-1)` ....but see my answer for how to combine that with a check for the 15th......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing you'll need is a list of all your bank holidays/public holidays and name the range holidays. Then this should work:

```
=IF(DAY(A1)=15,"Y",IF(A1=WORKDAY(DATE(YEAR(A1),MONTH(A1)+1,1),-1,holidays),"Y","N"))
```

With A1 being the first date it is looking at.

Comment: That wouldn't take into account situations where A1 is the 15th but is not a payday because it falls on a weekend or holiday.....

Answer (score 2):

With date in A2 try this formula

`=IF(OR(A2=WORKDAY(EOMONTH(A2,{-1,0})+{16,1},-1,holidays)),"Y","N")`

where holidays is a named range containing holiday dates

The formula finds the 16th of the current month and the 1st of the next (based on A2 date) and then finds the working day immediately **previous** to those dates (which will be 15th and end of month if those are working days, or the previous working day if not). If A2 is one of those dates you get "Y"